# How to get only one email id when clicked on name in contact list in android?

Tags: android, contacts

i want to get the only one email-id from contact list on clicking the contact list NAME in android. please help  me. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

public class PickEmailAddress extends Activity {
    private static final int EMAIL_REQUEST = 0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void launchContacts(View v){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setData(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, EMAIL_REQUEST);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode){
            case EMAIL_REQUEST:
                Uri selectedUri=data.getData();
                ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
                Cursor c=cr.query(selectedUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA}, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                String email=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                Toast.makeText(this, email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

keep read contacts permission in manifest.

Comment: The start activity for result doesn't work. It throws ActivityNotFoundException.