# Android contact picker that show email

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I need to select emails from contact... I find android have a build-in phone number picker as seen on image bellow.

img : http://i1108.photobucket.com/albums/h412/Tek_Yin/selectphone.jpg

in 1.5 & 1.6 I can use this :

`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI);`

the question is  :

- can it show email instead of phone number?
- I need it to adapt on 2.0 or higher
- I read 2.0 or higher is using `ContactsContract`, but how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164740/how-to-get-only-one-email-id-when-clicked-on-name-in-contact-list-in-android/4165522#4165522

Answer (score -2, accepted):

just override   @Override onActivityResult and create a cursor for email, when you get the results for picker, get only the email addreess.

```
email = Emailcursor.getString(Emailcursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can launch a contact picker that only displays email addresses using `ContactsContract` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: This works on Lollipop but not on Jelly Bean.
It opens a list of all email addresses but the result has resultCode = Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED and no data.

Comment: I forgort I had to grant my app runtime permissions to access contacts.. dope.